# Difference between heatmaps using heatmap3 and pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I have the following correlation matrix. The outputs for pheatmap and heatmap3 dendrograms are different despite apparently both using the 'complete' method for hierarchical clustering. Why am I getting different dendrograms?

Here is the correlation matrix:

```
dput(correlation_matrix)
structure(c(1, 0.666251970070319, 0.646678412860071, 0.645718486167484, 
0.654888925145033, 0.655822332711097, 0.576406212052306, 0.558206797280689, 
0.590062663833135, 0.571817833824497, 0.58604287486701, 0.595243296100497, 
0.62247655591197, 0.624092018633144, 0.63460702251327, 0.512215153977773, 
0.519438927895267, 0.506838954091303, 0.464366165490271, 0.437943929062139, 
0.421377957776993, 0.560123606870643, 0.568624902186355, 0.558166682821773, 
0.530285348919711, 0.6088011457415, 0.63362184851575, 0.472318427761061, 
0.554842161856539, 0.603865252606803, 0.569083737552, 0.574444748998412, 
0.567128618764448, 0.666251970070319, 1, 0.624979926607831, 0.618818043319178, 
0.623391803940144, 0.630495790006793, 0.560281503525621, 0.542270297762182, 
0.559514575497813, 0.557099061885663, 0.56395619973264, 0.568641953654156, 
0.589843377578331, 0.594975228470264, 0.595882156237437, 0.488263120190899, 
0.496523145373105, 0.483000654652344, 0.442996685594566, 0.424650038583426, 
0.406938560693056, 0.53597254217772, 0.54752050551923, 0.522943689352508, 
0.518383330041783, 0.586473943237914, 0.611634790714095, 0.466496770046608, 
0.53579123706761, 0.577926639777801, 0.542288561825199, 0.547125407537162, 
0.546256589205439, 0.646678412860071, 0.624979926607831, 1, 0.599296188967626, 
0.607635755494491, 0.602866665409841, 0.537184439599078, 0.52869423483373, 
0.548762797067245, 0.53611937529058, 0.554101250069951, 0.547135126501188, 
0.572250366966777, 0.576866480645401, 0.58359354769228, 0.475003707644263, 
0.477661372678301, 0.470265570254979, 0.427246270781391, 0.417137110920071, 
0.3960258913793, 0.526320775794967, 0.527491439017497, 0.516060130828032, 
0.500196103276352, 0.571576731688802, 0.5898484081872, 0.455768862965395, 
0.52892257208357, 0.556628870795877, 0.52931587236523, 0.537230429700976, 
0.533241882798821, 0.645718486167484, 0.618818043319178, 0.599296188967626, 
1, 0.780364552408059, 0.775690504545139, 0.600640252259414, 0.580781618869771, 
0.605805987779373, 0.602041872595327, 0.618368067224323, 0.621791946617339, 
0.623796145154549, 0.621627819214361, 0.628669682892074, 0.535664237915443, 
0.545427293691648, 0.531024438918821, 0.479891443400766, 0.454908873383366, 
0.43179893979235, 0.577103402675713, 0.586367308404628, 0.570979557253852, 
0.549709177316158, 0.634187365341402, 0.653329369935698, 0.508144778472103, 
0.591325555321588, 0.639193662917203, 0.606612063701124, 0.599597258685054, 
0.595489478801753, 0.654888925145033, 0.623391803940144, 0.607635755494491, 
0.780364552408059, 1, 0.795882130975682, 0.615178803881604, 0.591422912580522, 
0.622517870698621, 0.610720627814135, 0.633120279357322, 0.637688840405427, 
0.63832900555835, 0.640370589100891, 0.645716111438477, 0.547048073432981, 
0.555386329615679, 0.538631220350188, 0.495918098953116, 0.47055214848524, 
0.447379672661545, 0.587967939059872, 0.594437671853145, 0.583522572517011, 
0.55631543755339, 0.64271900960291, 0.664107588692682, 0.521672863313414, 
0.610243244759689, 0.652240725626234, 0.612582491421618, 0.617803918239427, 
0.607458638807306, 0.655822332711097, 0.630495790006793, 0.602866665409841, 
0.775690504545139, 0.795882130975682, 1, 0.607309020838382, 0.590285680143628, 
0.619168378597792, 0.615835170625958, 0.627534604593682, 0.636267321197323, 
0.634749760290175, 0.638358771241016, 0.644495615408113, 0.539506434389791, 
0.550476389536786, 0.533903161154981, 0.500300135034682, 0.471902188640364, 
0.44570525168204, 0.584539932144954, 0.593096756329301, 0.579939808783521, 
0.556428856188422, 0.637789732142358, 0.660970526763322, 0.516234283142566, 
0.601186664633615, 0.64266711513762, 0.609182626917735, 0.612437218259829, 
0.602459134622219, 0.576406212052306, 0.560281503525621, 0.537184439599078, 
0.600640252259414, 0.615178803881604, 0.607309020838382, 1, 0.581768722416872, 
0.608793001515374, 0.547209123451892, 0.561728275997811, 0.555999139467518, 
0.570908239684773, 0.583129965239241, 0.583158041554437, 0.479609224547631, 
0.489165697162638, 0.474136384580422, 0.424309861936206, 0.397948285285221, 
0.37775918696083, 0.525987714157774, 0.531075419522856, 0.512872489884773, 
0.501315630529199, 0.558620668822168, 0.575637696973186, 0.461374444297197, 
0.531651390914534, 0.574384128442894, 0.542015982553362, 0.545855037282148, 
0.53574161423446, 0.558206797280689, 0.542270297762182, 0.52869423483373, 
0.580781618869771, 0.591422912580522, 0.590285680143628, 0.581768722416872, 
1, 0.593406148685684, 0.530183135939598, 0.547380806363935, 0.543796207045695, 
0.557053904651564, 0.560233361888009, 0.561606828477471, 0.468482347955176, 
0.476974051389225, 0.463458945654529, 0.413409272828144, 0.39857897429728, 
0.378939269724302, 0.513198200045941, 0.520375173197121, 0.508983223522864, 
0.484609949339393, 0.544358657475334, 0.553375179164317, 0.448006716807121, 
0.517534048563084, 0.555514461088486, 0.52412078294762, 0.532692765990104, 
0.521602204430536, 0.590062663833135, 0.559514575497813, 0.548762797067245, 
0.605805987779373, 0.622517870698621, 0.619168378597792, 0.608793001515374, 
0.593406148685684, 1, 0.551783608616211, 0.567059359137719, 0.566944187632793, 
0.581567884320616, 0.586518425197473, 0.5914857419464, 0.487778829531766, 
0.493253122821652, 0.483392333120759, 0.437358500437534, 0.409534883031306, 
0.389977349346438, 0.539487204619599, 0.542868327108908, 0.532632141217739, 
0.504133899158159, 0.568476665449771, 0.585940308698928, 0.467817566826393, 
0.54584606774433, 0.583369732559789, 0.550719051991238, 0.556912822453729, 
0.546114388763365, 0.571817833824497, 0.557099061885663, 0.53611937529058, 
0.602041872595327, 0.610720627814135, 0.615835170625958, 0.547209123451892, 
0.530183135939598, 0.551783608616211, 1, 0.642738948793359, 0.634596942956872, 
0.590882730445589, 0.59083144895907, 0.594321274388379, 0.472801328516872, 
0.489513332211737, 0.469551073101825, 0.447089126234926, 0.428918996008575, 
0.404376907472003, 0.528290706969206, 0.535295673402742, 0.51545491343211, 
0.503579752921237, 0.573445673564243, 0.59426351640031, 0.473333782011235, 
0.549326565699238, 0.586798051767139, 0.547902625590255, 0.5577161097403, 
0.55299990741229, 0.58604287486701, 0.56395619973264, 0.554101250069951, 
0.618368067224323, 0.633120279357322, 0.627534604593682, 0.561728275997811, 
0.547380806363935, 0.567059359137719, 0.642738948793359, 1, 0.660858691716878, 
0.609203771350613, 0.610613732738629, 0.616038050057945, 0.497287813101831, 
0.500521433272851, 0.483915740122935, 0.458889077744141, 0.439835973673521, 
0.417170951450629, 0.545714233740054, 0.554588399954599, 0.53626355599897, 
0.52365018130578, 0.588884088523181, 0.611344355328401, 0.487042380621905, 
0.568449517078079, 0.609959353983681, 0.568322080127179, 0.579077791963023, 
0.571999798962751, 0.595243296100497, 0.568641953654156, 0.547135126501188, 
0.621791946617339, 0.637688840405427, 0.636267321197323, 0.555999139467518, 
0.543796207045695, 0.566944187632793, 0.634596942956872, 0.660858691716878, 
1, 0.609370927805179, 0.609665500216387, 0.613968250930436, 0.497377647014125, 
0.501015356692184, 0.490623068704645, 0.45975288630143, 0.441713680922735, 
0.419953370070982, 0.549494542457617, 0.555467747593073, 0.543084163680048, 
0.526649652841949, 0.594064124533003, 0.61200474554976, 0.494515284693201, 
0.567105414935146, 0.61255363515881, 0.580309326527274, 0.572905862145914, 
0.568943980030755, 0.62247655591197, 0.589843377578331, 0.572250366966777, 
0.623796145154549, 0.63832900555835, 0.634749760290175, 0.570908239684773, 
0.557053904651564, 0.581567884320616, 0.590882730445589, 0.609203771350613, 
0.609370927805179, 1, 0.726402738680219, 0.730385485592947, 0.470802895025039, 
0.480386809717669, 0.466490773301806, 0.488441723406674, 0.463845665685552, 
0.444930472708777, 0.532931619822557, 0.537446008776243, 0.522968641459032, 
0.519220028149436, 0.600342013467931, 0.617812822961583, 0.483795252081021, 
0.567490636754133, 0.609338183529622, 0.575597957992218, 0.584211361055306, 
0.572227386879758, 0.624092018633144, 0.594975228470264, 0.576866480645401, 
0.621627819214361, 0.640370589100891, 0.638358771241016, 0.583129965239241, 
0.560233361888009, 0.586518425197473, 0.59083144895907, 0.610613732738629, 
0.609665500216387, 0.726402738680219, 1, 0.73073751335856, 0.478348890898611, 
0.485168958500592, 0.473291960530279, 0.497520655240573, 0.466753954938195, 
0.442636571063409, 0.535492141214182, 0.540178322166431, 0.527514061832012, 
0.52465632091015, 0.600734790420976, 0.624601851643555, 0.488211334920567, 
0.558583679783909, 0.606463852657857, 0.585293144312056, 0.586523838806226, 
0.579705953759892, 0.63460702251327, 0.595882156237437, 0.58359354769228, 
0.628669682892074, 0.645716111438477, 0.644495615408113, 0.583158041554437, 
0.561606828477471, 0.5914857419464, 0.594321274388379, 0.616038050057945, 
0.613968250930436, 0.730385485592947, 0.73073751335856, 1, 0.489667886966059, 
0.493756405271286, 0.486626159313458, 0.493594296543732, 0.466995417935658, 
0.44303923268618, 0.546878160102285, 0.555180592780843, 0.543035918752307, 
0.53143355243547, 0.615123481223276, 0.627758788652321, 0.493063487203571, 
0.571268216809558, 0.619070372467881, 0.589857574742, 0.59301814762643, 
0.584497857877268, 0.512215153977773, 0.488263120190899, 0.475003707644263, 
0.535664237915443, 0.547048073432981, 0.539506434389791, 0.479609224547631, 
0.468482347955176, 0.487778829531766, 0.472801328516872, 0.497287813101831, 
0.497377647014125, 0.470802895025039, 0.478348890898611, 0.489667886966059, 
1, 0.573930115084326, 0.565767305078927, 0.387702266777113, 0.365855726725354, 
0.354651881949319, 0.48404290607174, 0.478802619514581, 0.478024855061985, 
0.45294375912975, 0.506938668808011, 0.514606579748803, 0.399472441141473, 
0.45990316802925, 0.493729279220098, 0.488102312687931, 0.485382507008592, 
0.479837535219824, 0.519438927895267, 0.496523145373105, 0.477661372678301, 
0.545427293691648, 0.555386329615679, 0.550476389536786, 0.489165697162638, 
0.476974051389225, 0.493253122821652, 0.489513332211737, 0.500521433272851, 
0.501015356692184, 0.480386809717669, 0.485168958500592, 0.493756405271286, 
0.573930115084326, 1, 0.56984462280155, 0.394523757237953, 0.370100966476821, 
0.362014379544163, 0.491380742468766, 0.497092533833708, 0.477600411367858, 
0.454025794803796, 0.51267282741019, 0.524937828774303, 0.40653894169176, 
0.468636001265335, 0.494276316469588, 0.491928337218319, 0.494219757125414, 
0.487321163738817, 0.506838954091303, 0.483000654652344, 0.470265570254979, 
0.531024438918821, 0.538631220350188, 0.533903161154981, 0.474136384580422, 
0.463458945654529, 0.483392333120759, 0.469551073101825, 0.483915740122935, 
0.490623068704645, 0.466490773301806, 0.473291960530279, 0.486626159313458, 
0.565767305078927, 0.56984462280155, 1, 0.388233911320604, 0.36694620841273, 
0.347718426206711, 0.480448057946823, 0.479364531232873, 0.469876505140902, 
0.453942456703348, 0.500257589712416, 0.516681508045186, 0.400479514797986, 
0.458352331917852, 0.485677095666497, 0.473775086679793, 0.481131897323956, 
0.4729706622375, 0.464366165490271, 0.442996685594566, 0.427246270781391, 
0.479891443400766, 0.495918098953116, 0.500300135034682, 0.424309861936206, 
0.413409272828144, 0.437358500437534, 0.447089126234926, 0.458889077744141, 
0.45975288630143, 0.488441723406674, 0.497520655240573, 0.493594296543732, 
0.387702266777113, 0.394523757237953, 0.388233911320604, 1, 0.443545975911721, 
0.420944923287646, 0.40435312389074, 0.414150290563465, 0.405648076067145, 
0.398409065824734, 0.447422540379301, 0.461022118102035, 0.37814393838321, 
0.434886967202501, 0.471932450759584, 0.442323936523553, 0.446245921089844, 
0.439161110179349, 0.437943929062139, 0.424650038583426, 0.417137110920071, 
0.454908873383366, 0.47055214848524, 0.471902188640364, 0.397948285285221, 
0.39857897429728, 0.409534883031306, 0.428918996008575, 0.439835973673521, 
0.441713680922735, 0.463845665685552, 0.466753954938195, 0.466995417935658, 
0.365855726725354, 0.370100966476821, 0.36694620841273, 0.443545975911721, 
1, 0.405612575296481, 0.3930427012973, 0.390865813962098, 0.387140493405081, 
0.367300983618806, 0.425185016852878, 0.435086481041775, 0.365080528918633, 
0.418043543275075, 0.451719008459014, 0.430741363505893, 0.428650391896923, 
0.40841969521299, 0.421377957776993, 0.406938560693056, 0.3960258913793, 
0.43179893979235, 0.447379672661545, 0.44570525168204, 0.37775918696083, 
0.378939269724302, 0.389977349346438, 0.404376907472003, 0.417170951450629, 
0.419953370070982, 0.444930472708777, 0.442636571063409, 0.44303923268618, 
0.354651881949319, 0.362014379544163, 0.347718426206711, 0.420944923287646, 
0.405612575296481, 1, 0.376374668394522, 0.378376602183698, 0.370220222479995, 
0.359256904734502, 0.405101385317096, 0.42325408450936, 0.346075327022492, 
0.396537363311061, 0.427468195395397, 0.390879925896947, 0.403941125223864, 
0.394195677936578, 0.560123606870643, 0.53597254217772, 0.526320775794967, 
0.577103402675713, 0.587967939059872, 0.584539932144954, 0.525987714157774, 
0.513198200045941, 0.539487204619599, 0.528290706969206, 0.545714233740054, 
0.549494542457617, 0.532931619822557, 0.535492141214182, 0.546878160102285, 
0.48404290607174, 0.491380742468766, 0.480448057946823, 0.40435312389074, 
0.3930427012973, 0.376374668394522, 1, 0.586840456428439, 0.579766198639395, 
0.499802105815994, 0.560642458536544, 0.570716733845865, 0.446822548204979, 
0.515802226009571, 0.553576203125076, 0.521070464329165, 0.526285311142317, 
0.521639929684202, 0.568624902186355, 0.54752050551923, 0.527491439017497, 
0.586367308404628, 0.594437671853145, 0.593096756329301, 0.531075419522856, 
0.520375173197121, 0.542868327108908, 0.535295673402742, 0.554588399954599, 
0.555467747593073, 0.537446008776243, 0.540178322166431, 0.555180592780843, 
0.478802619514581, 0.497092533833708, 0.479364531232873, 0.414150290563465, 
0.390865813962098, 0.378376602183698, 0.586840456428439, 1, 0.578836119388687, 
0.500100158976043, 0.56579633303267, 0.577554635016008, 0.45019293610374, 
0.52139842572515, 0.556406576058404, 0.528595150554007, 0.529620890893181, 
0.52282379449972, 0.558166682821773, 0.522943689352508, 0.516060130828032, 
0.570979557253852, 0.583522572517011, 0.579939808783521, 0.512872489884773, 
0.508983223522864, 0.532632141217739, 0.51545491343211, 0.53626355599897, 
0.543084163680048, 0.522968641459032, 0.527514061832012, 0.543035918752307, 
0.478024855061985, 0.477600411367858, 0.469876505140902, 0.405648076067145, 
0.387140493405081, 0.370220222479995, 0.579766198639395, 0.578836119388687, 
1, 0.488981219100935, 0.550675794821383, 0.565873081245155, 0.429089750026928, 
0.507573734842833, 0.539795574687822, 0.525662445782108, 0.52496001625139, 
0.516718205980963, 0.530285348919711, 0.518383330041783, 0.500196103276352, 
0.549709177316158, 0.55631543755339, 0.556428856188422, 0.501315630529199, 
0.484609949339393, 0.504133899158159, 0.503579752921237, 0.52365018130578, 
0.526649652841949, 0.519220028149436, 0.52465632091015, 0.53143355243547, 
0.45294375912975, 0.454025794803796, 0.453942456703348, 0.398409065824734, 
0.367300983618806, 0.359256904734502, 0.499802105815994, 0.500100158976043, 
0.488981219100935, 1, 0.582706743738247, 0.600523856306344, 0.449041740551315, 
0.501164385801353, 0.526615334780805, 0.485713899812535, 0.486738071301846, 
0.487932598004854, 0.6088011457415, 0.586473943237914, 0.571576731688802, 
0.634187365341402, 0.64271900960291, 0.637789732142358, 0.558620668822168, 
0.544358657475334, 0.568476665449771, 0.573445673564243, 0.588884088523181, 
0.594064124533003, 0.600342013467931, 0.600734790420976, 0.615123481223276, 
0.506938668808011, 0.51267282741019, 0.500257589712416, 0.447422540379301, 
0.425185016852878, 0.405101385317096, 0.560642458536544, 0.56579633303267, 
0.550675794821383, 0.582706743738247, 1, 0.678863897554573, 0.479828124443035, 
0.562206032683777, 0.598501904549762, 0.555098701657363, 0.557361070220099, 
0.546725903990333, 0.63362184851575, 0.611634790714095, 0.5898484081872, 
0.653329369935698, 0.664107588692682, 0.660970526763322, 0.575637696973186, 
0.553375179164317, 0.585940308698928, 0.59426351640031, 0.611344355328401, 
0.61200474554976, 0.617812822961583, 0.624601851643555, 0.627758788652321, 
0.514606579748803, 0.524937828774303, 0.516681508045186, 0.461022118102035, 
0.435086481041775, 0.42325408450936, 0.570716733845865, 0.577554635016008, 
0.565873081245155, 0.600523856306344, 0.678863897554573, 1, 0.495301276023668, 
0.573868145902551, 0.616589452009719, 0.567842234176287, 0.566886983421791, 
0.560568683911729, 0.472318427761061, 0.466496770046608, 0.455768862965395, 
0.508144778472103, 0.521672863313414, 0.516234283142566, 0.461374444297197, 
0.448006716807121, 0.467817566826393, 0.473333782011235, 0.487042380621905, 
0.494515284693201, 0.483795252081021, 0.488211334920567, 0.493063487203571, 
0.399472441141473, 0.40653894169176, 0.400479514797986, 0.37814393838321, 
0.365080528918633, 0.346075327022492, 0.446822548204979, 0.45019293610374, 
0.429089750026928, 0.449041740551315, 0.479828124443035, 0.495301276023668, 
1, 0.532127752686445, 0.555612701728572, 0.465137364164243, 0.47334240115451, 
0.462166812798642, 0.554842161856539, 0.53579123706761, 0.52892257208357, 
0.591325555321588, 0.610243244759689, 0.601186664633615, 0.531651390914534, 
0.517534048563084, 0.54584606774433, 0.549326565699238, 0.568449517078079, 
0.567105414935146, 0.567490636754133, 0.558583679783909, 0.571268216809558, 
0.45990316802925, 0.468636001265335, 0.458352331917852, 0.434886967202501, 
0.418043543275075, 0.396537363311061, 0.515802226009571, 0.52139842572515, 
0.507573734842833, 0.501164385801353, 0.562206032683777, 0.573868145902551, 
0.532127752686445, 1, 0.645670104868729, 0.534228490856768, 0.537318394935805, 
0.531139215830187, 0.603865252606803, 0.577926639777801, 0.556628870795877, 
0.639193662917203, 0.652240725626234, 0.64266711513762, 0.574384128442894, 
0.555514461088486, 0.583369732559789, 0.586798051767139, 0.609959353983681, 
0.61255363515881, 0.609338183529622, 0.606463852657857, 0.619070372467881, 
0.493729279220098, 0.494276316469588, 0.485677095666497, 0.471932450759584, 
0.451719008459014, 0.427468195395397, 0.553576203125076, 0.556406576058404, 
0.539795574687822, 0.526615334780805, 0.598501904549762, 0.616589452009719, 
0.555612701728572, 0.645670104868729, 1, 0.574087711059237, 0.586918921255433, 
0.576934255095412, 0.569083737552, 0.542288561825199, 0.52931587236523, 
0.606612063701124, 0.612582491421618, 0.609182626917735, 0.542015982553362, 
0.52412078294762, 0.550719051991238, 0.547902625590255, 0.568322080127179, 
0.580309326527274, 0.575597957992218, 0.585293144312056, 0.589857574742, 
0.488102312687931, 0.491928337218319, 0.473775086679793, 0.442323936523553, 
0.430741363505893, 0.390879925896947, 0.521070464329165, 0.528595150554007, 
0.525662445782108, 0.485713899812535, 0.555098701657363, 0.567842234176287, 
0.465137364164243, 0.534228490856768, 0.574087711059237, 1, 0.66844457358031, 
0.652343405846023, 0.574444748998412, 0.547125407537162, 0.537230429700976, 
0.599597258685054, 0.617803918239427, 0.612437218259829, 0.545855037282148, 
0.532692765990104, 0.556912822453729, 0.5577161097403, 0.579077791963023, 
0.572905862145914, 0.584211361055306, 0.586523838806226, 0.59301814762643, 
0.485382507008592, 0.494219757125414, 0.481131897323956, 0.446245921089844, 
0.428650391896923, 0.403941125223864, 0.526285311142317, 0.529620890893181, 
0.52496001625139, 0.486738071301846, 0.557361070220099, 0.566886983421791, 
0.47334240115451, 0.537318394935805, 0.586918921255433, 0.66844457358031, 
1, 0.650995156792667, 0.567128618764448, 0.546256589205439, 0.533241882798821, 
0.595489478801753, 0.607458638807306, 0.602459134622219, 0.53574161423446, 
0.521602204430536, 0.546114388763365, 0.55299990741229, 0.571999798962751, 
0.568943980030755, 0.572227386879758, 0.579705953759892, 0.584497857877268, 
0.479837535219824, 0.487321163738817, 0.4729706622375, 0.439161110179349, 
0.40841969521299, 0.394195677936578, 0.521639929684202, 0.52282379449972, 
0.516718205980963, 0.487932598004854, 0.546725903990333, 0.560568683911729, 
0.462166812798642, 0.531139215830187, 0.576934255095412, 0.652343405846023, 
0.650995156792667, 1), .Dim = c(33L, 33L), .Dimnames = list(c("line_04_R1", 
"line_04_R2", "line_04_R3", "line_05_R1", "line_05_R2", "line_05_R3", 
"line_06_R1", "line_06_R2", "line_06_R3", "line_07_R1", "line_07_R2", 
"line_07_R3", "line_08_R1", "line_08_R2", "line_08_R3", "line_09_R1", 
"line_09_R2", "line_09_R3", "line_10_R1", "line_10_R2", "line_10_R3", 
"line_11_R1", "line_11_R2", "line_11_R3", "line_12_R1", "line_12_R2", 
"line_12_R3", "line_13_R1", "line_13_R2", "line_13_R3", "line_14_R1", 
"line_14_R2", "line_14_R3"), c("line_04_R1", "line_04_R2", "line_04_R3", 
"line_05_R1", "line_05_R2", "line_05_R3", "line_06_R1", "line_06_R2", 
"line_06_R3", "line_07_R1", "line_07_R2", "line_07_R3", "line_08_R1", 
"line_08_R2", "line_08_R3", "line_09_R1", "line_09_R2", "line_09_R3", 
"line_10_R1", "line_10_R2", "line_10_R3", "line_11_R1", "line_11_R2", 
"line_11_R3", "line_12_R1", "line_12_R2", "line_12_R3", "line_13_R1", 
"line_13_R2", "line_13_R3", "line_14_R1", "line_14_R2", "line_14_R3"
)))
```

Here is my code for heatmap3:

```
colour_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#F0F0F0", "#DB5634"))(50)
heatmap3(correlation_matrix, col = colour_palette, scale = "none", sym = TRUE, margins = c(9, 9))
```

and for pheatmap:

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(mat = correlation_matrix, color = colorRampPalette(c("white","gray", "#FFADAD", "#FF7070", "#FF0000"))(100))
```

Why are the dendrograms different? Thanks!

[image: heatmap3]

[image: pheatmap]